# Which PHP ORM for CodeIgniter with PHP 5.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, php-5.2

Hey,
normally im developing with doctrine 2.0 and CodeIgniter with PHP 5.3x
Now i hav to work with php 5.2 for one site and im asking which orm should i take because Doctrine2 needs PHP 5.3x

Should i simply use doctrine 1.2 for my site? Has anyone experiences with this version or is there another good orm?

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend DataMapper:

Source:
https://bitbucket.org/wanwizard/datamapper

Forum: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/178045/

Home Page: http://stensi.com/datamapper/

The docs are great, the syntax is intuitive, and it is very powerful and easy to extend, and most importantly in your case, it only requires php 5.0

It is actively developed, and WanWizard is also very helpful and responsive on the forums.

Comment: Please note that this ORM cannot use with exists database as it has its rule for name the table's field.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend NotORM

http://www.notorm.com/

It's easy to use, it's use the SimpleXML object chaining concept for database relation, and use PDO for query execution

Comment: Bear in mind that multi-column FKs are not supported. Also, it looks like you can't rebuild the database from a schema, which is not great if you are distributing your application (since you'd have to manually write build sql for each db platform you plan to support). Nevertheless, looks like an interesting project.